# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string error 4

Tags: c#

how do I solve this error that i get when I try insert data into a table.
The error that I get is

" Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"
here is my code:

Comment: try to use `Parameters` and provide the values using 'PrameterWithValue' `Method`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace string concatenation with parameters:

```
Query = "INSERT INTO TblModules (Module_Code, Module_Name, Date,Start_Time, Duration) values (@ModuleCode, @Modulename, @date, @Start_Time, @Duration);";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ModuleCode", ModuleCodeTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Modulename", ModulenameTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", Setdate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Start_Time", comboBoxTime.SelectedItem);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Duration", comboBoxDuration.SelectedItem);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score -1):

> here is a sample code , working good

```
DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(Date.Text);
            SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM  Tech_data where Call_assign= @Call_assign and dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0, [date_time]), 0) = @date_time ");
            cmnd.Connection = con;
            cmnd.Parameters.Add("@Call_assign", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Label1.Text;
            cmnd.Parameters.Add("@date_time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datetime.Date;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmnd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
```